# IIS 6 Virtual Directory created without the asp.net application extensions

Tags: c#, iis, iis-6

I have a configuration page that needs to create a virtual directory under a new virtual application.  The method for creating this directory is distinct for the version of IIS, with the IIS 7 installs using the newer management controls.  The IIS 7 installs create the virtual directory and add the expected asp.net application extensions.  The following code, used for IIS 6, does create the virtual directory, however it does not add the asp.net application extensions as you can see in the image below.  How do I modify my code to ensure the expected asp.net application extensions get added?

[image]

```
private void AddDirIis6(DirectoryEntry entry)
{
    var child = entry.Children.Add("EditorControls", "IIsWebVirtualDir");
    child.Properties["Path"][0] = "directory\EditorControls");

    child.CommitChanges();
    entry.CommitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the script mappings are missing for your site.  You can either run

`aspnet_regiis -s W3SVC/1/ROOT/SampleApp1`

with your application specified for the last parameter instead of the sample one or

`aspnet_regiis -i`

Be aware that -i installs the script maps for ALL sites on IIS.

You will need to execute the aspnet_regiis for the correct version of the framework you are using.  Instructions to do this are in the instructions for the aspnet_regiis tool:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: This virtual directory is under another virtual application.  The top level application has the expected iis mappings.  The virtual directory does not.  I will try this suggestion, however I wanted to make that clear.

Comment: I tried running both of these, and my virtual remains without the script mappings

Comment: @JonEdiger can you post a screen shot of the Home Directory tab in IIS 6.0 manager for your virtual directory?

Comment: I did another deep dive into the code and found my real issue: the code wasn't mapping all the required extensions on the virtual directory/application.  The answer given is a great one to remember. I appreciate the help.